# print the first three months as a string in python

Tags: python

```
day = 1
month = 3
for x in range(3):
    while day <= 31:
        print(str(month)+"/"+str(day)+"/2019'")
        day += 1
    month += 1
```

I am trying to print the first 31 days from March-May. (I know April has 30 days, but I am not concerned with that.
The while loop works, printing out the first 31 days in march. The code does not loop through 2 more times and increment the month to sequentially print out the 31 days for April and May.
I am used to Java for loops and I am not familiar iterating over an nondeclared variable.

Comment: You don't reset `day` back to 1 in the outer loop. Once you've printed the first month, `day` is still at `31` so the inner loop never runs again.

Comment: Move the `day=1` to inside your `for` loop. Also you could remove the `month=3` and just use `for month in range(3,7)`

Comment: take a look at the [`datetime` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html), which has a lot of tools for manipulating dates!

Answer (score 0):

You need to reset the `day` back to one inside the outer loop otherwise `day` stays at 31 the second time through the loop. You can do this by moving the assignment inside the loop:

```
month = 3
for x in range(3):
    day = 1
    while day <= 31:
        print(str(month)+"/"+str(day)+"/2019'")
        day += 1
    month += 1
```

Having said that, it's easier just to use for loops:

```
for month in range(3, 6):
    for day in range(1, 32):
        print(f"{month}/{day}/2019")
```

Answer (score 0):

The only problem is that the variable `day` is not being reseted once a new month starts. You need to move the declaration `day=1` inside the for-loop:

```
month = 3
for x in range(3):
    day = 1
    while day <= 31:
        print(str(month)+"/"+str(day)+"/2019'")
        day += 1
    month += 1
```